# Compiler error for classes and methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-controls

I'm getting an error for items such as void / sender / class etc when attempting to paste in this example of a viewstate into Visual studio. I know that the methods need to be inside a class, but even that is still bringing up an error. The code needs to be inside a script in a web control and I'm wondering what's bringing up the errors. I've tried it in a different solution / project and changing the framework, no luck.

The code is

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Umbraco.cms.businesslogic" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="umbraco.cms.businesslogic.propertytype" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="umbraco.cms.businesslogic.relation" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="umbraco.nodefactory" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.ComponentModel" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="TemplateEngine.Docx" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing" %>

<script> 

public class PageStateTemplate
{
   new umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.Document(document location);

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        if(!IsPostBack)
         {
            string str = "Welcome to Aspdotnet-Suresh Site";
         if(ViewState["SampleText"]==null)
         {
             ViewState["SampleText"] = str;
         }

         }
   }

   protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    lblString.Text = ViewState["SampleText"].ToString();
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Post the exact error message, and the line.

Comment: `new umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.Document(document location);` this line is invalid because of `document location` - variables cannot contains spaces, arguments must be divided with comma. And you also don't assign your new Document to any variable, is it ok?

Comment: That's not the issue since it's flagging up "class" as an error. All it says is "expected ;" and it's flaggingu p class, void, sender

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a new aspx page with the name **PageStateTemplate** and copy paste the whole code into the .aspx file.

That should do it

Comment: It has to be a web user control to integrate with Umbraco.